# Embedded C Compiler Source include Vs linking

Tags: c, compiler-construction, sdcc

I have a bunch of source files for my application, should I just source include create one object file or let them be separate and let the linker do the job. Which one is more efficient?.

Comment: It's more a question of maintainability than efficiency.  Let the linker do the job.  What you are proposing only scales so far.

Answer (score 3):

Please make each one a separate object file and link them together ... Otherwise, life will be painful, not just for debugging by you, but for anyone else that will attempt to even try to understand what the heck is going on with your code ...